# mv command failed now file missing

Tags: linux, bash, php, mv

So i ran mv command and it failed with

```
mv: cannot stat ‘/root/HIDDENDIR/HIDDEN-DIR/recover.php’: No such file or directory
```

And now file is missing from original and target directory. I even tried `find` on whole server and no luck there

I ran mv command from PHP by exec and after that i used exec with chmod and chown.

If it helps this is exact exec command:

```
exec("mv \"".$file[1]."\" \"".$file[0]."\"");
```

Is file deleted or just lost somewhere (and if deleted any way to recover it?)

EDIT: Both directories are on same filesystem.

Comment: The original and the target directory – are they on the same filesystem?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, they are.

Comment: The message is obvious, the file disappeared **before** the mv command was issued, so you have to wonder what happened before that command.

Comment: @xenoid Well my thought was that file was never actually in there before it is like quarantine folder for files and another script moved them there, but no way to check it now, but log from mv files from folder to quarantine never showed any errors. But no other commands were run from PHP script that caused errors. So only possible reason for this is that someone or some other script did something to those files before mv command was issued?

Comment: The file can have been removed by an action that didn't generate an error. IN fact, of the command was successful in removing the file, it likely didn't generate any error.

Comment: @xenoid So is it possible that mv removed file, showed no error, even there was specified from and to folder?

Comment: Not the `mv` execution above (but perhaps a previous execution)

Comment: @xenoid Wel i ran mv with verbose option and output was this: `‘/var/www/FOLDER/FOLDER0/FOLDER2/web/FOLDER/FOLDER/FOLDER/lvwrjlkx.php’ -> ‘/root/FOLDER/SUB-FOLDER/lvwrjlkx.php’`
That doesn't look like successful deletion of file. I just need to know if this is problem with mv command or something else so I know where to search for problem

Comment: Check if you are trying to move symbolic link instead of real file. When symbolic link is moved to another place it is obviously broken.

Comment: @OlegBolden Good idea, but nope those aren't sym links.